# Custom logstash index in Fluend with timestamp

Tags: logstash, fluentd

I'm trying to setup a fluentd service to collect logs and send them to elastic search.

All is good, except I cannot get a custom index name AND keep the timestamp similar to what `logstash_format: true` would have.

Here is my fluent.conf file:

```
<source>
  @type forward
  port 24224
  bind 0.0.0.0
</source>
<match *.**>
  @type copy
  <store>
    @type elasticsearch
    hosts hostaddressandport
    user theuser
    password password
    include_tag_key true
    tag_key @log_name
    index_name myindex-%Y.%m
    <buffer>
      flush_interval 3s
    </buffer>
  </store>
</match>
```

The index gets created in elastic literally and it shows `myindex-%Y.%m` I've tried myindex-${%Y.%m} and get the same behaviour.

If I use `logstash_format: true` instead, then I get an index like `logstash-2019.07.09`, but I don't want that.

This is where I'm getting my idea from https://docs.fluentd.org/output/elasticsearch but I don't see the expected behaviour.

I have found the following in the docs mentioned above:

```
<buffer tag, time>
  timekey 1h # chunks per hours ("3600" also available)
</buffer>
```

But it's pretty vague and I don't understand what chunk_keys are.

Comment: Can you try this and let me know if it works?. `index_name "myindex-%Y.%m"` which is moving quotes outside.

Comment: Didn't work for me either? Did you find any solution to this

Answer (score 0):

You can use `logstash_format` and `logstash_prefix` to change the index prefix. This will not use the date format you require though.

```
logstash_format true
logstash_prefix myindex
```

Answer (score 0):

please use this config  you will get your custom date format for your index name

Config file

```
<source>
  @type forward
  port 24224
  bind 0.0.0.0
</source>
<match *.**>
  @type copy
  <store>
    @type elasticsearch
    hosts hostaddressandport
    user theuser
    password password
    include_tag_key true
    tag_key @log_name
    logstash_format true
    logstash_dateformat %Y.%m
    logstash_prefix index_name
    <buffer>
      flush_interval 3s
    </buffer>
  </store>
</match>
```

output

```
indexname-2021.08
```